# Retrieve JSON array with $.getJSON and return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a json object that looks like this.

```
[{
    "bannerName": "HotWire",
    "imgLocation": "img/logo/weh.jpg",
    "profiles":["1000000390","1000000391"],
    "locations":["1","250"]
},
{

    "bannerName": "The Grill",
    "imgLocation": "img/logo/weh123.jpg",
    "profiles":["1000000390","1000000391"],
    "locations":["1","250"]
}];
```

which is saved in banners.json

I am trying to retrieve this information to create banners with bootstrap.

I am using the following to retrieve the info from the json file.

```
$.getJSON('banners/banners.json', function(data){

  $.each(data, function(index, obj){
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
      console.log(value);
    });
  });

});
```

However, nothing is logged in the console. Essentially, what I need is to retrieve the info within the loop as variables so I can embed them in HTML but I can't seem to return anything with this code.

Comment: Your code works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eyxzX/ Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Check the value of `data` that is being returned, as I think that's the problem.  It works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/5kVm2/

Comment: Do you have a semicolon at the end of the data structure in the .json file?

Comment: any error in your browser console? can you add a logging statement before the success callback to see whether the success callback is called... also add a `fail` handler to see whether the ajax request is failed

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove semicolon at the end in json if any

```
[{
    "bannerName": "HotWire",
    "imgLocation": "img/logo/weh.jpg",
    "profiles":["1000000390","1000000391"],
    "locations":["1","250"]
},
{

    "bannerName": "The Grill",
    "imgLocation": "img/logo/weh123.jpg",
    "profiles":["1000000390","1000000391"],
    "locations":["1","250"]
}]
```

You can check in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) whether your json is correct

```
$.getJSON('banners/banners.json', function(data){
 // try to debug what you actually getting
  console.log(data);
});
```